# NULL != NULL in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a query that sees if fields are equivalent. However, whenever the field is NULL it returns a false result. I even tried doing the same thing with the column itself:

```
SELECT * FROM `mturk_completion` WHERE (`mturk_completion`.`imdb_url` =  
`mturk_completion`.`imdb_url` AND `mturk_completion`.`worker_id` = 'A3NF84Q37D7F35' )
```

And it only returns results where the column is not NULL. Why is this so, and how do I get around it?

Comment: Which field, specifically? Also, what is intended by this statement "`mturk_completion`.`imdb_url` =  
`mturk_completion`.`imdb_url`"? As far as I know, the contents of a column will always equal the contents of the same column.

Comment: Except if the column contains `NULL` values. The `NULL` values don't `equate` to other `NULL` values. The `=` operator just returns a `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your title is absolutely correct for any SQL implementation (not just MySQL). `NULL` **is not equal to anything** (including another `NULL`).

You need to use explicit [`IS NULL`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/is_null.php) check or [`COALESCE()` function (or its RDBMS-dependent alternatives)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) to set some default value in case of `NULL`.

Comment: Also [null-safe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator.

Answer (score 4):

Your comparison of `mturk_completion.imdb_url` to itself is redundant and should always return True, except when `mturk_completion.imdb_url`is Null, in which case it will return Null.

That's because the operator `=` returns either `True`, `False` when comparisons can be made or `Null`, when either of the two operators is Null

Try this to illustrate the situation.

```
SELECT 1 = NULL; -- returns NULL
SELECT 1 != NULL; -- also return NULL
SELECT ISNULL(1 = NULL); -- returns 1
SELECT ISNULL(1 != NULL); -- returns 1
```

If you rewrite your query like below, your problems with ignoring NULLs will go away:

```
SELECT * FROM `mturk_completion` WHERE worker_id = 'A3NF84Q37D7F35'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
(table.Field =  table2.Field OR COALESCE(table.Field, table2.Field) IS NULL)
```